# can't open display and xhost issue

Tags: ssh, xhost

I create a vncserver at a serverA

```
vncserver :20
```

I succeed to use vncviewer access serverA (IP_of_serverA:20.0)

At another serverB, I hope export the display to serverA:20.0

At serverA

```
setenv DISPLAY IP_of_serverA:20.0
xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
# *** no any warnings/errors
```

At serverB

```
setenv DISPLAY IP_of_serverA:20.0
xeyes
xeyes: Can't open display
```

However, if I use ssh X11forwarding.

At serverA (use vncviewer)

```
ssh -X -Y serverB
xeyes
# *** succeed to open application
```

For this display configure is something like "localhost:N.0" and value of "N" is different for every connection.  But I need to write script for auto run something, I hope DISPLAY setting is unique.

It seems open "DISPLAY IP_of_serverA:20.0" fail is due to "xhost" NOT set properly. Any method to check xhost setting/configure?  OR any others stuff will block/limit the access of serverA from serverB?